# Describe/drawing two linear function relate to each other on the same coordinate system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I am having a hard time describing how two linear function relate to each other and drawing the second one

The first one:$$f(x) =\begin{cases}  -\frac x3 -\frac{4}{3} & \ -1  \le x<2 \\  3x -8 & 2\le x\le 5 \end{cases}$$

The second one: $y=f(\frac{x}{3})$

I have tried drawing them

[image]

Comment: You draw the $f(x)$ (black graph) correctly ( I assume there is one segment between points (-1,-1) and (2,-2) though it seems two segments).

Comment: yeah, but what about the other one ? and how do I describe how they are related ?

Comment: If you stretch the graph of  $f(x)$ you obtain $f(\frac{x}{3})$ You can see this after drawing $f(\frac{x}{3})$. because the domain of $f(\frac{x}{3})$ is larger

Comment: is that all ? and what about your deleted comment do I need to place the $x/3$ inside the first one like you mentioned or not ?

Comment: Sorry I accidently deleted that comment.

Comment: Place $\frac{x}{3}$ and you obtain : $f(\frac {x}{3}) =\begin{cases}  -\frac x9 -\frac{4}{3} & \ -3  \le x<6 \\  x -8 & 6\le x\le 15 \end{cases}$  Then draw its graph

Comment: By the way here is my deleted comment:      "In order to graph $f(\frac{x}{3})$ all you need to do is putting $\frac{x}{3}$ instead of $x$ in the equations and in the inequality and you obtain: $f(\frac{x}{3}) =\begin{cases} -\frac x9 -\frac{4}{3} & \ -1 \le \frac x3<2 \\ x -8 & 2\le \frac x3\le 5 \end{cases}$ Or: $f(\frac{x}{3}) =\begin{cases} -\frac x9 -\frac{4}{3} & \ -3 \le x<6 \\ x -8 & 6\le x\le 15 \end{cases}$"

Comment: dont know if you want to answer the question or should I answer it but thanks anyway just wanted to give you at least points for bothering with my dumbass I dont know today has been a rough day cant seem to do math at all sry again

Comment: You are welcome!